# PLSQL retonar erro ao obter dados do Banco

Tags: java, oracle, pl-sql

Tento extrair dados no banco e inserir em um registro e depois mostrar no cmd,
Porém quando obtenho um numero maior numero de registro o procedimento exige uma mensagem de erro.

**Codigo:**

```
SET SERVEROUTPUT ON
DECLARE
  TYPE trec IS RECORD ( 
    cd_multi_empresa NUMBER(8,2),
    tp_atendimento   CHAR(2)
  );

vcAtendimento trec;
cAtendimento VARCHAR2(1000) := 'select cd_multi_empresa,tp_atendimento from cli.atendime FETCH FIRST 2 ROWS ONLY';

BEGIN
  Dbms_Output.Put_Line('inicio');
    EXECUTE IMMEDIATE cAtendimento INTO vcAtendimento; 
    Dbms_Output.Put_Line(vcAtendimento.tp_atendimento);
  Dbms_Output.Put_Line('fim');
END;
/
```

**Mensagem de Erro:**

> Relatório de erros - ORA-01422: a extração exata retorna mais do que o
>   número solicitado de linhas ORA-06512: em line 12
>   01422. 00000 -  "exact fetch returns more than requested number of rows"
>   *Cause:    The number specified in exact fetch is less than the rows returned.
>   *Action:   Rewrite the query or change number of rows requested inicio

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Este erro acontece porque sua consulta retorna mais que um registro, e o record suporta apenas 1.

Para retornar vários vocês precisa trabalhar com coleções, fazendo uma table of record e preenchendo com o comando bulk collect

ex:

```
create table Teste1 (c1 number, c2 number);
insert into teste1 values (1, 1);
insert into teste1 values (2, 2);
-----------------

declare
  type TTeste is record(
    campo1 number,
    campo2 number);

  type TTesteTAB is table of TTeste;
  vTeste TTesteTAB;

  ConsultaDinamica varchar(200) := 'select * from teste1';
begin
  execute immediate ConsultaDinamica Bulk Collect
    into vTeste;
  dbms_output.put_line('Quantidade de registros: ' || vteste.count);
  dbms_output.put_line('Registro 1, campo1: ' || vteste(1).campo1);
  dbms_output.put_line('Registro 2, campo1: ' || vteste(2).campo1);
end;
```